Power BI Geo mapping; Bing maps and Azure maps
I have Power BI Pro. The sole reason is that I must publicly post Geomaps on the web.
By this, I want to share Geopmaps with a public link from Power BI services.
After being told by Powor BI that I should use Azue maps, which I did, I found out that you can not share them publicly.
So I used a Bubble map (Bing map), but now I have discovered that MS will depreciate them.
I would like to know before I get too far down this path if

Will Azure maps become publicly accessible shortly
Will Bing maps be deprecated if Azure maps are not publically sharable

Thanks to anyone with insight/knowledge into this topic

Sorry @Sampath, xyz is saying that he cannot share Azure maps publicly.... and you share the Azure maps documentation. This makes no sense. What sort of an help that should be? Maybe you should read the documentation.

This is so strange and I think we are hitting a wall here.
All you said it's true:

Azure Maps: Power BI publish to web = No
Bing Maps: In a future release, Power BI plans to deprecate older map visuals and migrate existing reports to Azure Maps.

So Microsoft will deprecate everything that is not Azure Maps and is pushing everyone to adopt Azure Maps.
Azure Maps cannot be shared publicly.
It's a shame and I don't know what to suggest to you.

Maybe try Bing Maps as long as they are free and sharable (risking the fact that 1 day from now or 10 years from now they will be deprecated and you have to re-do everything.)
Try for Power BI visuals alternatives:


It's a shame.
Try whatever works.

Thank you for your comment. As far as I can tell, Bing maps will be around until June 30th, 2028. Hopefully, by then, Azure maps will be sharable publicly. I did look into alternative after-market Geomaping apps, and there are a few of them, but WOW, are they expensive! Prohibadily so.

I can easily parse my data into a Google sheet. I found this. It looks promising and is affordable. https://www.thexs.ca/xsmapping/advanced-premium-plan-subscription

Alright, so the the whole point of this question was to create a backlink to your website.

No, it was how to use Power BI with a Geomap that was reliable. Which does not seem to be possible. Therefore, a different potential solution is needed. I do not have any connection to the link, I posted it in case anyone finds this question and needing similar can check it out
